# Subquery returned more than 1 value.The subquery that contains SUM(dbo.SalarySettingsBreakup.Amount) AS AmountSSB

Tags: sql, sql-server

My sub-query returns more than one value and gives error.

```
(SELECT dbo.employee.id, 
        dbo.employee.employeecode, 
        dbo.employee.firstname, 
        dbo.employee.departmentid, 
        dbo.salarysettings.monthlyoffered, 
        dbo.salarysettings.id       AS SalarySettingsID, 
        (SELECT Sum(amount) AS AmountVP 
         FROM   voucherprocesses 
         WHERE  vouchertypeid = 2 
                AND employee = dbo.employee.id 
                AND voucherdate BETWEEN '9/1/2017 12:00:00 AM' AND 
                                        '9/30/2017 12:00:00 AM' 
         GROUP  BY employee)        AS SalaryAdvance, 
        (SELECT Sum(dbo.salarysettingsbreakup.amount) AS AmountSSB 
         FROM   dbo.employee 
                LEFT JOIN dbo.salarysettings 
                       ON dbo.employee.id = dbo.salarysettings.employee 
                LEFT JOIN dbo.salarysettingsbreakup 
                       ON dbo.salarysettings.id = 
                          dbo.salarysettingsbreakup.salarysetting 
         WHERE  dbo.salarysettingsbreakup.paymenttype = 2 
                AND dbo.salarysettingsbreakup.isactive = 1 
         GROUP  BY dbo.employee.id) AS TotalDeduction, 
        (SELECT CASE 
                  WHEN employee.joiningdate BETWEEN 
                       '9/1/2017 12:00:00 AM' AND '9/30/2017 12:00:00 AM' THEN( 
                ( salarysettings.monthlyoffered / 30 ) * ( 30 - 
                ( Datepart(dd, joiningdate) - 1 ) ) ) 
                  ELSE 0 
                END)                AS PayToBank 
 FROM   dbo.employee 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.salarysettings 
               ON dbo.employee.id = dbo.salarysettings.employee 
 WHERE  dbo.salarysettings.isactive = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

hope will work, try this :

```
(SELECT e.id, 
        e.employeecode, 
        e.firstname, 
        e.departmentid, 
        dbo.salarysettings.monthlyoffered, 
        dbo.salarysettings.id       AS SalarySettingsID, 
        (SELECT Sum(amount) AS AmountVP 
         FROM   voucherprocesses 
         WHERE  vouchertypeid = 2 
                AND voucherprocesses.employee = e.id 
                AND voucherdate BETWEEN '9/1/2017 12:00:00 AM' AND 
                                        '9/30/2017 12:00:00 AM' 
         )        AS SalaryAdvance, 
        (SELECT Sum(dbo.salarysettingsbreakup.amount) AS AmountSSB 
         FROM   dbo.employee e2
                LEFT JOIN dbo.salarysettings 
                       ON e2.id = dbo.salarysettings.employee

                LEFT JOIN dbo.salarysettingsbreakup 
                       ON dbo.salarysettings.id = 
                          dbo.salarysettingsbreakup.salarysetting 
                       AND dbo.salarysettingsbreakup.paymenttype = 2
                       AND dbo.salarysettingsbreakup.isactive = 1
         WHERE e2.id = e.id
         ) AS TotalDeduction, 
        (SELECT CASE 
                  WHEN employee.joiningdate BETWEEN 
                       '9/1/2017 12:00:00 AM' AND '9/30/2017 12:00:00 AM' THEN( 
                ( salarysettings.monthlyoffered / 30 ) * ( 30 - 
                ( Datepart(dd, joiningdate) - 1 ) ) ) 
                  ELSE 0 
                END)                AS PayToBank 
 FROM   dbo.employee e
        LEFT JOIN dbo.salarysettings 
               ON e.id = dbo.salarysettings.employee 
 WHERE  dbo.salarysettings.isactive = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have much to learn. You need to understand how subqueries work as well as outer joins. The following is wrong due to 2 issues.

```
(SELECT Sum(dbo.salarysettingsbreakup.amount) AS AmountSSB 
     FROM   dbo.employee 
            LEFT JOIN dbo.salarysettings 
                   ON dbo.employee.id = dbo.salarysettings.employee 
            LEFT JOIN dbo.salarysettingsbreakup 
                   ON dbo.salarysettings.id = 
                      dbo.salarysettingsbreakup.salarysetting 
     WHERE  dbo.salarysettingsbreakup.paymenttype = 2 
            AND dbo.salarysettingsbreakup.isactive = 1 
     GROUP  BY dbo.employee.id) AS TotalDeduction,
```

First is that you did not properly correlate the subquery. As Rahmat posted (but did not explain), you need to associate the employee ID from the outer query with the subquery. Because you did not correlate the subquery, it produces multiple rows for each row in the outer query - producing your error.

In addition, your lack of understanding about the correlation causes you to add complexity and a logical mistake (which gets covered up when correlated correctly). There is no need to include the employee table in your subquery. Since you correlate it to the employee table in the main query, it is redundant. In addition, you don't need to group by anything in the subquery since it is intended to generate a single scalar value per row in the outer query. And lastly, there is no purpose to outer joining in the subquery. Either you have matching rows in salarysettingsbreakup or you don't. An inner and outer join will achieve the same result - NULL if no matches. I also question whether you need to sum at all given the table and column names involved. You should search for explanations about how outer joins work and what happens when you reference columns from the unpreserved table (e.g. salarysettingsbreakup) in the where clause.

So a better subquery is:

```
(SELECT Sum(bkp.amount)  
FROM dbo.salarysettings as sset 
INNER JOIN dbo.salarysettingsbreakup as bkp
    ON sset.id = bkp.salarysetting 
    AND bkp.paymenttype = 2
    AND bkp.isactive = 1
WHERE sset.employee = dbo.employee.id) as TotalDeduction,
```

Note the inclusion of some best practices. Give a readable alias to your tables and use it with all of the columns referenced. I also despise the practice of using a table name as a column name - that adds to the confusion of reading your queries IMO.